# Why does this code produce an incomplete IP address?

Tags: c, arp

I am reading a buffer from a socket (AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_ARP)) with the following code. I am using an arp_frame struct to access the component parts of the contained ARP reply. The inet_ntoa() returns the correct first octet of the IP but the other octets are 0 producing 172.0.0.0.

Question 1 is why might this happen?
Question 2 is how can I print r bytes of the msg buffer as hex in host byte order to debug the packet?

```
    unsigned char msg[65535];
    struct ether_arp *arp_frame = (struct ether_arp *)msg;

    while ((r = recv(sock, msg, sizeof(msg), 0))) {
            // skip it's not an ARP REPLY
            if (ntohs(arp_frame->arp_op) != ARPOP_REPLY)
                    continue;

            for (i = 0; i < SONOS_PREFIX_NUM; i++) {
                    if (!memcmp(sonos_prefixes[i], arp_frame->arp_sha, 3)) {
                            struct in_addr addr;
                            addr.s_addr = *arp_frame->arp_spa;

                            printf("Blah: %lu\n", ntohl(*arp_frame->arp_spa));
                            printf("Sonos found at %s\n", inet_ntoa(addr));
                    }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct ether_arp` looks like this:

```
struct  ether_arp {
    struct  arphdr ea_hdr;          /* fixed-size header */
    u_int8_t arp_sha[ETH_ALEN];     /* sender hardware address */
    u_int8_t arp_spa[4];            /* sender protocol address */
    u_int8_t arp_tha[ETH_ALEN];     /* target hardware address */
    u_int8_t arp_tpa[4];            /* target protocol address */
};
```

With that in mind, I think that your `addr.s_addr = *arp_frame->arp_spa;` looks a little fishy. `arp_frame->arp_spa` yields a `u_int8_t[4]`, which you then dereference as a pointer. I think `memcpy()` might be more appropriate there.

Comment: Bawls. Seems I consulted entirely the wrong manual as it said it was a u_long - http://www.propox.com/download/edunet_doc/all/html/structether__arp.html. Thanks :)

Comment: It probably depends on the platform... On big-endian systems where byte-reversal isn't required, it could conveniently be stored as a 32-bit integer, but on little-endian systems, I guess it would depend on the implementation of `ntohl()` and friends that the implementers chose... Even if it's an unsigned int/long, though, treating it as a pointer isn't right...

Answer (score 0):

If you think the API is broken, print out the bytes.

"Methinks, Brutus, the fault is not in the stars."

Comment: You'll see that I'm filtering to make sure these are replies. I should also note that this is the source address, not the destination address and that the code produces 172.0.0.0 for all parsed ARP replies.

Comment: Having now seen the correct answer, the only part of this answer that is useful is "If you think the API is broken, print out the bytes."